# Yellowbrick learningCurve: chage legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, yellowbrick

I want to plot the learning curve of train and validation set using yellowbrick learning curve.
I am not using cross validation when plotting the learning curve, but a hold out validation set. Anyway, the legend is fixed to "Cross validation score".

Is there a way to replace it with another string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Viz` returns the axes object in the ax property, you can use it to set the label like that:

```
viz.ax.get_lines()[1].set_label('My custom label')
```

[Example](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/model_selection/validation_curve-1.py):

```
import numpy as np

from yellowbrick.datasets import load_energy
from yellowbrick.model_selection import ValidationCurve

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

# Load a regression dataset
X, y = load_energy()

viz = ValidationCurve(
    DecisionTreeRegressor(), param_name="max_depth",
    param_range=np.arange(1, 11), cv=10, scoring="r2"
)

# Fit and show the visualizer
viz.fit(X, y)
viz.ax.get_lines()[1].set_label('My custom label')
viz.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly what I needed to know!